# Is this sequence monotone or not?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am stuck on a calculus problem.

Namely, I am trying to determine if the following sequence: $$a_n = \frac{2+3^n}{n!-1}$$ is monotone or not (for all integer values of $n>1$).

Thanks.

Comment: You can learn about formatting your formulae using Latex [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: a_1 is not defined.

Comment: @John Apologies for that, I improved the formatting without looking at the actual sequence. I've just fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

We have $$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{\left(2+3^{n+1}\right)(n!-1)}{\left(2+3^{n}\right)((n+1)!-1)}<\frac{3}{n+1}\le1$$ as a consequence of $$2+3^{n+1}<3 \left(2+3^{n}\right)=6+3^{n+1}$$ and $$n!-1<\frac{(n+1)!-1}{n+1}=n!-\frac{1}{n+1}.$$ Hence, $a_n$ is monotonically decreasing for all $n>1$.

Comment: I am really confused, how did you get this?

Comment: @Kerrrrrr $$2+3^{n+1}<3 \left(2+3^{n}\right)=6+3^{n+1}$$ and $$n!-1<\frac{(n+1)!-1}{n+1}=n!-\frac{1}{n+1}.$$

Comment: @Kerr Sorry, previously I had to answer quickly. I've added an explanation, is it clearer now?

Comment: Yes, it is. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Kerr Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $$
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac{n!-1}{(n+1)n! - 1} \frac{2+3^{n+1}}{2+3^n}= \frac{1-\frac{1}{n!}}{1-\frac{1}{(n+1)!}}\frac{1}{n+1}\frac{3+\frac{2}{3^n}}{1+\frac{2}{3^n}}
<\frac{1}{n+1}\frac{3+\frac{2}{3^n}}{1+\frac{2}{3^n}} < \frac{3}{n+1}
$$
So for $n \geq 2$, $a_{n+1}<a_n$

Your question must have meant $n>1$ since for $n = 1$ the denominator is zero.

Thus the function is monotone decreasing for all $n > 1$.

Answer (score 0):

$$b_n=\dfrac{2}{n!-1},\quad c_n=\dfrac{3^n}{n!-1}$$
$b_n$ is clearly decreasing.
$$\dfrac{c_{n+1}}{c_n}=3\dfrac{n!-1}{(n+1)!-1}$$
For all $n\geq 2$ it is true that $$(n+1)!-1>(n+1)!-3=(n+1)n!-3\geq 3n!-3=3(n!-1)$$ 
$\dfrac{c_{n+1}}{c_n}<1$ and $c_n$ is decreasing.
$$a_n=b_n+c_n,$$ so $a_n$ is decreasing.